# Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module - Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a import.tf file which includes the following code

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-rg" {
   name = "existingrg"
}
```

I then run the command as below

```
terraform import "azurerm_resource_group.example-rg"  "/subscriptions/123456-789-123-1111-123/resourceGroups/existingrg"
```

I've tried numerous articles but still getting the below error when trying to import

```
Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-rg" {
      # (resource arguments)
    }
```

Also does the import.tf need to be in a separate folder to where the main.tf file is? What is the root module is it main.tf or import.tf ?

Comment: You need to provide all the required arguments even when importing, so I would try by adding the `location` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here root module refers to the `main.tf` code. And in your case the `main.tf` should contains the resource group deployment with all the required fields.

Firstly, to import any resource the resource should be existed previously. And for creating the resource group with terraform, there is a template to follow and it is clearly given in [terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group). You need to pass all the required parameters while creating it. Then only the deployment will get succeeded.

***I created a resource group in my environment and deployed it as shown.***

```bash
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-rg" {
   name = "existingrg"
   location = "eastus"
}
```

***Deployed successfully:***

[image]

Now, If I wanted to import it into `terraform state` file after it is destroyed, I used `terraform import` command.

```
terraform import  azurerm_resource_group.example-rg "<resourceID>"
```

*resourceID structure: "/subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/existingrg"*

Once I created the resource group with the respective template and destroyed, I tried importing into terraform state file and was successfully worked.

[image]

Now you can be able to see this configuration in `terraform state` file.